# Move files into specifics folders with almost same patterns

Tags: bash

I have actually a directory where I have different file such as :

So let say in the directory : `/path1/ncbi_genomes`

```
Sp_1.fna
Sp_2.fna
Sp_3.fna
Sp_4.fna
Sp_5.fna
```

and another directory with folders such as: /path2/path2.1

```
Sp_1
Sp_2
Sp_3
Sp_4
Sp_5
```

So what I would like to do is to put these `.fa` files present in the directory `/path1/ncbi_genomes` in the corresponding folder in the directory `/path2/path2.1`

Corresponding mean that the name of the file is the same as the name of the folder in the directory `/path2/path2.1`

I should get at the end :

```
Sp_1
  Sp_1.fna
Sp_2
  Sp_2.fna
Sp_3
 Sp_3.fna
Sp_4
 Sp_4.fna
Sp_5
 Sp_5.fna
```

I tried `for i in *; do mv`$i.fna `/path2/path2.1/$i/;` done` but it did not work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because your `$i` contains `.fna`. [Remove the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) and it should work.

Try this,

```
for i in *; do
    mv "$i" "/path2/path2.1/${i%.*}";
done
```

If the path does not exist, run `mkdir -p "/path2/path2.1/${i%.*}"` before `mv`.